# executing function after function with ajax call has completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to know which way is the best way to execute a function when a function with the ajax call has completed.

My code:

```
   jQuery.when(AjaxCallToBokningar()).done(function () {

            console.log("AjaxCallComplete");
        });


    function AjaxCallToBokningar() {
    var url = `${_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Bokningar')/items

    var call = jQuery.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
        }
    });

    //Done
    call.done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        //Filling globalArray
        window.globalBokningsArray = data.d.results;
    });

    //Fail
    call.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log('Loading Bokningar content faild: ' + textStatus + jqXHR.responseText);
    });
}
```

Am I on the right track or is there a better way?

Comment: You already have it there - `call.done()` is the callback method that runs after the Ajax call is complete.

Comment: I know, but I use the call two times and I Would like to put the logic that happens after the call elsewhere.

Comment: You can always define the function elsewhere and do something like `call.done(updateBokningsArray)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to make the Ajax call and then call a function when it's complete you can use a function reference as a parameter and do it like this...

```
function AjaxCallToBokningar(doneCallback) {
    var url = `${_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Bokningar')/items

    var call = jQuery.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
        }
    });

    //Done
    call.done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        //Filling globalArray
        window.globalBokningsArray = data.d.results;
        doneCallback();
    });

    //Fail
    call.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log('Loading Bokningar content faild: ' + textStatus + jqXHR.responseText);
    });
}
```

Then you can call it like this...

```
function ajaxCallComplete1() {
    // this is executed after the 1st call is done - do something here 
}

function ajaxCallComplete2() {
    // this is executed after the 2nd call is done - do something here 
}

AjaxCallToBokningar(ajaxCallComplete1);
AjaxCallToBokningar(ajaxCallComplete2);
```

or...

```
AjaxCallToBokningar(function() {
    // this is executed after the call is done - do something here 
});
```

Comment: the code breaks at `doneCallback();`  Errormessage: `Uncaught TypeError: doneCallback is not a function`

Comment: Have you added it as a parameter to the function call, and is it actually referencing a function?

Comment: my bad. I will be back with the result

Comment: Thank you alot. It works! This is very useful code for the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try something like this: (not tested)

```
function ajaxCallToBokningar() {
  var url = `${_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Bokningar')/items`;
  var options = {
    url: url,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
    }
  };

  return jQuery.ajax(options);
}


function updateBoknigarArray(data) {
  window.globalBokningsArray = data.d.results;
}

function showError(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  console.log('Loading Bokningar content faild: ' + textStatus + jqXHR.responseText);
}

ajaxCallToBoknigar()
  .done(updateBoknigarArray)
  .fail(showError)
```